# Unable to install kernel driver rpm during %post section kickstart RHEL7

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to install a custom driver rpm that I custom built. I have a kickstart file bundled into a RHEL7.2 iso with a `%post` section. In the `%post`, I have a yum install of the driver rpm which seems to get installed, but I notice that depmod logs fatal errors when the driver rpm gets installed:

> ```
> Installing : kmod-xnxx-1.0-1_test.x86_64
> depmod: FATAL: could not load 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64: No such file or directory
> warning: %post(kmod-xnxx-1.0-1_test.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
> Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package kmod-xnxx-1.0-1_test.x86_64
>  Verifying  :  kmod-xnxx-1.0-1_test.x86_64
> Installed :
>   kmod-xnxx-1.0-1_test.x86_64
> Complete!
> ```

As the rpm gets installed, it runs a depmod -a and dracut to rebuild the ramdisk. I'm not sure why these errors a re occurring during the anaconda post install? I've confirmed that the same kernel "3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64" is being used during the post so I have no idea why the module doesn't get installed correctly without the "depmod" errors. I recall from the past that the running kernel during the anaconda install has differences with the kernel that actually gets installed. I'm not sure if this is attributed to the issue I'm having with the post. Any suggestions on how to overcome this would be great. Thanks!

Below is the spec file that I'm using to build the kernel driver rpm(kmod) against kernel 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64:

```
%define build_kernel 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64

%define current_kernel %(uname -r)

%define destdir /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/

Summary: driver

Name: kmod-xnxx

Version: 1.0

Release: 1_test

License: GPL

Group: Hardware driver

BuildArch: x86_64

BuildRoot: %{buildroot}


%description
Creating a xn4xx kernel module RPM

%prep

%install

mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{destdir}

if [ “%{build_kernel}” != “%{current_kernel}” ]; then
echo “This rpm is for %{build_kernel} kernel version. Ensure that you are using right module/kernel”
exit 1
fi

ls %{destdir} > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]; then
echo “%{destdir} is not there. Unable to install the driver.”
exit 1
fi

install -m 644 %(pwd)/BUILD/xnxx.ko %{buildroot}%{destdir}xnxx.ko

%clean

rm -rf %{buildroot}

%post

/sbin/depmod -a %{current_kernel}

/sbin/dracut -v -f /boot/initramfs-%{current_kernel}.img %{current_kernel}

%files

%defattr(-,root,root)

%{destdir}xnxx.ko


%changelog
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `depmod` with the same parameters from command line? If this results in the same error, then it is not a `rpm` issue, but only relates to `depmod`.

Comment: Yes I'm able to run the depmod -a command after installation when the system boots back into multiuser. For some reason I can't get it to work during the anaconda kickstart install. The system needs to have the rpm loaded upon reboot from the kickstart, but depmod keeps erroring out.

Comment: I resolved this issue by changing the %post section of the rpm from "depmod -a 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64" to "depmod 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64" once the rpm gets installed. Thanks.

Comment: I think your problem is that in `%post` it *might* still be running the anaconda kernel, not the installed. You need something run at first boot to ensure it is target kernel. However, RPMs for drivers are a real pain. The official Fedora stance is [don't do it](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#No_External_Kernel_Modules). What happens when the user updates their kernel? Are you going to make them reinstall your driver every time? Because your modules will be in `/lib/modules/old_kernel_version/` and not where you want.